# Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 0- Data frame creation issue

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am trying to create a data frame and the data frame has been created like below:

```
2005 40.96250 40.73171
2006 40.77922 41.38596
2007 38.92683 40.76829
2008 36.09756 39.54430
2009 38.83562 37.97368
2010 33.89024 35.47222
2011 38.48276 35.45000
2012 38.62821 36.69444
2013 29.50000 32.59494
2014 34.48571 34.88750
```

But I am getting the following error message in the console.

> "Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of
>   rows: 10, 0"

I tried the following code and got the error message

```
a<- Seasons

 b <-  MinutesPlayed[rownames(MinutesPlayed) %in% 
 c(input$player1)]/Games[rownames(Games) %in% c(input$player1)]

 c <-  MinutesPlayed[rownames(MinutesPlayed) %in% 
 c(input$player2)]/Games[rownames(Games) %in% c(input$player2)]

plotdata <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Data for the creation of data frames

```
Seasons <- c("2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014")
```

Minutes Played matrix looks like this(Data):

```
              2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
    KobeBryant 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000
    JoeJohnson 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
   LeBronJames 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000
CarmeloAnthony 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000
  DwightHoward 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
    ChrisBosh  1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000
    ChrisPaul  3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000 3000
   KevinDurant 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000
   DerrickRose 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000
```

Games Matrix looks like this(Data):

```
             2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 
    KobeBryant 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
    JoeJohnson 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
   LeBronJames 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
CarmeloAnthony 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
  DwightHoward 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
    ChrisBosh  50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
    ChrisPaul  50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
   KevinDurant 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
   DerrickRose 50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50
```

where
input$player1 ,input$player2 are the players selected by the user in the  selectInput choices.

Both the selectInput have the following players:

```
   KobeBryant 
    JoeJohnson
   LeBronJames 
CarmeloAnthony 
  DwightHoward 
    ChrisBosh  
    ChrisPaul  
   KevinDurant
   DerrickRose
```

UI.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(


      dashboardPage(
        skin='blue',
        dashboardHeader(title = "Players"),
        sidebar =  dashboardSidebar(
          width = 230,
          sidebarMenu(
            sidebarMenu(
              selectInput(inputId="player1", label="Player 1", choices=as.character(Players), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE),
              uiOutput('player2')         
            )
          )))
```

SERVER.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$player2 = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId="player2", label="Player 2", choices=as.character(Players[Players != input$player1]), selected = input$player2, multiple = FALSE)
  })
  output$minutes <- renderPlot({
    a<- Seasons
    b <-  MinutesPlayed[rownames(MinutesPlayed) %in% c(input$player1)]/Games[rownames(Games) %in% c(input$player1)]
    c <-  MinutesPlayed[rownames(MinutesPlayed) %in% c(input$player2)]/Games[rownames(Games) %in% c(input$player2)]
    plotdata <- data.frame(a,b,c)
})
})
```

> The error message is displayed only when the Shiny application
>   launches.I don't  see the error message when the input choices are
>   switched by the user.

Comment: If the user selects a player not in the rownames of those two data frames, your subset operation will return all `FALSE`, yielding a data frame with 0 rows, causing the error

Comment: The rownames of the two data frames have all the players and so my subset operation for the data frames always return TRUE. I think something else is causing the error

Comment: Well, without being able to see the input there's no way to know what's causing the issue

Comment: I will edit the question with the exact input

Comment: Can you look into the issue now?

Comment: Please edit the question to include your input selector code.

Comment: Also please specify *when* the warning appears. Is it there when your shiny app starts? Or only after your make/change selections. Is it repeated every time you change selections, or just the first time? Or just for certain selections?

Comment: I think the problem might be in part related to the way you subset `MinutesPlated` and `Games`. You're comparing `rownames` with an input to get a logical vector, but then you use that to grab columns. Probably you want to do `MinutesPlayed[...,]` so you select rows based on that.

Comment: I have added the input selector code. The error is displayed only when the Shiny application starts.